# How to roughly import .js libraries without type declaration in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I'm using Vue.js with cli and starting project on Typescript. I didn't have any problem with it except of cases when I have to use js libraries. I know about this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped and I use it when possible. But there is one big problem when js library is new, old or unpopular and has no type definitions. I spend a lot of time, looking for solution and it seems like there is only few of options:

- Use existing types i.e. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
- Write own *.d.ts files
- Use explicit js import, as is, without proper type definitions and intellisense

In my case first option is unavailable. Second - very depends on library, which may have difficult structure to declare. 
So, what I can do if I want just import js library as is?
I tried these ways:

```
import { } from 'velocity-animate';
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
import { Velocity } from 'velocity-animate';
import Velocity from '../../node_modules/velocity-animate';
import * as Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
const Velocity = require('velocity-animate');
const Velocity: any = require('velocity-animate');
const Velocity = require('../../node_modules/velocity-animate/velocity.js');
```

Also, tried add different variations and combinations with imports above like:

```
declare var Velocity: any;
declare module 'velocity-animate';
```

etc. And nothing, I just have errors in console like:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined

It's not my typo in code, in regular js same code works fine i.e.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLBZMd

Another my suspicion is tscompiler and his rules/settings. Here is mine:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "googlemaps"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Why so simple thing causes so big problems?

Comment: The approaches above cheat typing system, so this wouldn't cause type errors at compilation time, while `Uncaught ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined` is runtime error. `Velocity` global variable is expected *somewhere* to exist, and it doesn't exist. It's impossible to say where the problem happens. You're the only person who can do that. Error output contains call stack. Check it. It's possible that Velocity lib requires Webpack configuration to be fine-tuned - which wasn't mentioned in the question. Any way, this is not type declaration problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined

This is a *runtime* error not a *compile time typescript error*.

## Fix

Make sure `Velocity` global is available. e.g. add : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js as a `script` tag *before* your application code runs.

Comment: I did so and it's working, but not optimal for production build. Is there any other way to import js like this, but using import or require()? Any ideas?